# Extremely weird behavior in fread(); read entire string when printing string but says it did not reached EOF and reaches EOF when it did not

Tags: c, io, fread

I'm getting some weird behavior in the following function:

```c
char* read_file(const char* filename) {
  FILE* file = fopen(filename, "rb"); // error check

  fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END); // error check this too
  unsigned int size = ftell(file); // error check

  rewind(file);

  // I know a char is a single byte, but just for readibility's sake:

  char* buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * size + 1); // error check

  unsigned int result = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), size, file); // more error check

  fclose(file);
  // puts(buffer); // see the rest of the question, this is line 16
  return buffer;
}
```

If line 16 stays commented, I get undefined behavior in my program, i.e. the string returned was not what I expected, i.e. an error happened. And with error checking I spare the question from having, I'm getting that `result` is equal to `size`, so fread read the file successfully. Now, if I uncomment line 16 and print the result, everything works and no undefined behavior happens. Why might this be happening?

Comment: How does the calling code know how long the buffer is?  You don't even write a null byte in the extra byte you've allocated.  The `puts()` might be reading beyond the bounds of the allocated memory because of that — or it might be stopping short because there's a null in the file.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally include a [mre], which includes a function `main`, all `#include` directives, the exact contents of the input file, the expected output and the actual output of the program.

Comment: Also, note that dual tagging a question with C and C++ is a way to earn downvotes. Which language are you writing in?  Use that tag — and only that tag.  Actually, your code is invalid in C++ (because you don't cast the result of `malloc()`), so you must be using C.  You shouldn't use `malloc()` in idiomatic C++ anyway.

Comment: Why are you writing `// error check`? Is it to say to us that in your real code you're performing an error check? Or do you believe that this code is error checking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`malloc` allocates uninitialized storage, which means the contents of the returned buffer is not initialized to zero.

You allocate a buffer of `size + 1` bytes, and then read `size` bytes from the file into it. That final byte in the buffer, the one you got because of that `+ 1`? You never wrote anything to it. That string is missing its null terminator, and `fread` won't do that for you.

You'll have to add the null terminator yourself, otherwise `puts` will hit undefined behaviour trying to print it:

```
buffer[result] = '\0';
```

Comment: Using `buffer[result] = '\0';` and `puts(buffer)` will not print all the data if the data read includes a `'\0'`.  `puts(buffer)` will also append a `'\n'`, even if not in the data.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [@Etienne de Martel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70562135/2410359) good answer, OP's code had other weaknesses.

**No check for open success**

```
  FILE* file = fopen(filename, "rb"); // error check
  
  // add
  if (file == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable t open file <%s>\n", filename);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
```

**No error check, Unneeded `L`**

```
  //fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END); // error check this too

  if (fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END)) {
    // add error message here
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
```

**Wrong type, no error check**

```
  // unsigned int size = ftell(file);

  // ftell returns a long
  long size = ftell(file);
  if (size == -1) {
    // add error message here
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  rewind(file);  // this is OK
```

**No size error check, conceptual wrong multiplication, no allocation check**

```
  // char* buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * size + 1); // error check

  if (size < 0 || size >= SIZE_MAX) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Size %ld was to large to convert to size_t\n", size);
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  // Even though it makes no arithmetic difference as sizeof(char) is 1,
  // multiply the size of the object by the _sum_
  // char* buffer = malloc(sizeof(char) * (size + 1));
  
  // Even better as, size by the referenced object, not type 
  char* buffer = malloc(sizeof buffer[0] * (size + 1));

  // Add allocation check
  if (buffer == NULL) {
    // add error message here
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
```

**Use correct return type, add result check**

```
  // unsigned int result = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), size, file);
  // fread returns a size_t
  // size_t result = fread(buffer, sizeof(char), size, file);
  // Even better as
  size_t result = fread(buffer, sizeof buffer[0], size, file);
   
  if (result != size) {
    // add error message here
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
      
  fclose(file); // OK
```

**Finally we get to OP's most pressing problem**

Code attempts to print using `puts(buffer)` which expects `buffer` to be a *string*.  The character array `buffer[]` is not certainly a string as it may lack a *null character*.

Various solutions: append a *null character*.

```
  // Make certain `buffer[]` contains a final '\0'.
  buffer[result] = '\0';
  // then print 
  puts(buffer);
```

Or print using `fwrite()`, which does not need `buffer[]` as a *string*.

```
  fwrite(buffer, sizeof buffer[0], result, stdout);
```

**Deeper**

Remaining problems:

- Data was read using `"rb"` and writing with `stdout` (either with `puts()` or `fwrite()`.  This creates issues on some platforms as writing in *text_mode* (`stdout` typical default mode) the binary data `"\r\n"` may print as `"\r\r\n"`.  Work-around: re-open `stdout` in binary mode.
- Data read may contain *null characters*, in which case `puts()` will stop early at the first `'\0'` - not the appended one.  `fwrite()` avoids this issue.
- File size may exceed `LONG_MAX` or `SIZE_MAX` or exceed `malloc()` available memory.  We need to determine file size another way and allocate differently to cope with such huge files.
- On unusual systems the `fseek(), ftell()` trick does not work.  The best solution involves not needing to read the entire file into one array/string, but into many blocks.  Leaves details of that for another day.

Comment: OP already states "And with error checking I spare the question from having", so I'm guessing they just left out the error checking, so I don't think it was necessary to write most of this.

Comment: @Etienne de Martel, OP non-code quote describes unseen code whose correctness is not certain and based on code comments is certainly incomplete.